# HttpInterceptor not calling Global Error Handler

Tags: angular

I am performing a spike to investigate the global error handler within Angular, I am trying to simulate client side and server side errors but when I force a http error(fake end point) the errors seem to get outputted to the console instead of getting dealt with the error handler, meaning they don't even call through to the error handler.

ErrorHandler

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GlobalErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {

  constructor(private injector: Injector) { }

    handleError(error: Error | HttpErrorResponse): void {
      const errorService = this.injector.get(ErrorService);
      const notifier = this.injector.get(NotificationService);

      let message;
      let stackTrace;
      if(error instanceof HttpErrorResponse){
          //Server error
          message = errorService.getServerMessage(error);
          stackTrace = errorService.getServerStack(error);
      }else{
          //Client Error
          message = errorService.getClientMessage(error);
          stackTrace = errorService.getClientStack(error);
      }
      notifier.showError(message);
    }
}
```

Interceptor

```
export class ServerErrorInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor() { }

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        return next.handle(req).pipe(
            catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
                    // client-side error or network error

                } else {
                    // TODO: Clean up following by introducing method
                    if (error.status === 498) {
                        // TODO: Destroy local session; redirect to /login
                    }
                    if (error.status === 401) {
                        // TODO: Permission denied; show toast
                    }
                }
                return throwError(error);
            })
        )
    }
}
```

Module provider:

```
providers: [
    { provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: GlobalErrorHandler },
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: ServerErrorInterceptorService, multi: true}
]
```

and component:

```
    export class ErrorHandlingComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  numberArray: number[];

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  causeError(){
       this.numberArray[-1] = 1;
  }

    causeServerSideError() {
        this.httpClient.get("STUB URL").subscribe((x: number[]) => this.numberArray = x)
    }
}
```